# THT decoupling capacitor spacing from the TQFP uC's power pin

Tags: surface-mount, pcb-fabrication, through-hole, clearance, spacing

How close can the uC's power pin (TQFP pad) and a ceramic cap's PTH pin can get so the PCB fabrication process or later exploitation would not go wrong?
Some ballpark figures for common equipment available in most fabrication houses are desired. uC is going to draw current from a 3.3 V rail.

Comment: Is depending of the the voltage on the uC's power pin see in the Printed Board Design standards such IPC-2221A

Comment: Is your question "go wrong" referring to electrical safety, or to the manufacturing process? I can't tell you how well the manual solder people can solder... that's something you have to ask them.

Comment: @MarcusMüller edited and - now going through IPC-2221A.

Comment: Why don't you use SMD capacitors?

Comment: @LeonHeller Good idea, but I am the one who is going to do the hand soldering :)

Comment: @kellogs With a bit of practice and a friendly package size (0805/0603) they're not really harder than through hole, but perform better. I usually find it quicker to solder a board of surface mount than through hole parts now. Less turning it over and clipping things.

Comment: @RDjorane according to the IPC-2221A standard, paragraph 8.1.8, it seems my clearance would be 0.75 mm. This looks like a no problem figure for today's fab houses, so I am happy with that. You may want to turn it into an answer as well. Thanks!

Comment: Is just a small comment not an answer